# Android Spinner. How do I delete an item from the spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm creating a flight app. I have 2 spinners: `spinOrigin` and `spinDestination`;
I also have `m_array` for the items I want to put on the spinners: "`Place1`","`Place2`", and "`Place3`".

What I want to achieve is if I chose "`Place1`" from spinner `spinOrigin`, "`Place1`" should be deleted so that only "`Place2`" and "`Place3`" will be left to choose from from spinner `spinDestination`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the element from your `ArrayAdapter<String>`
2. Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, it will update the spinner automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove that element from your `ArrayAdapter<String>` that you apply to your `Spinner` and apply that adapter again to your `Spinner` to refresh it.